# Why am I getting an empty array and incorrect data fetching in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, promise, use-effect

I have two buttons, the `movies` and `tvshows` button. When I click on either I change the `option` to the opposite one as shown on the `handleMovieClick` and `handleTVShowsClick` methods. Movies and TVshows may have the same id, that is why the `option` is important for fetching.

I am printing to the console.

(1) `array` of movie/tv ids

(2) the `option` selected

(3) each individual object fetched based on the `id` and `option`

When I use the `value` to calculate the `array` of movie ids available the first time, I first get an empty array and then the expected result. That is the `array` of movie ids, option is movie and each individual promise objects is fulfilled.

Here's the kicker, when I click on the `tvshows` button, I am getting the following two things consoled.

(1) same movie `array` of ids not updated, option changes to `tv`, however I get a bunch of promises with "status_message: "The resource you requested could not be found" because I am basically trying to retrieve promises with movie ids, but tvshow option.

Then,

(2) Then the result is changed and I everything as expected. That is option stays the same, changed in above step, the `array` gets updated, and the individual promise objects are all fulfilled.

What is happening?

I get that it is happening because of the code in my JSX where I am making use of the `array` ids. I think I need to only call the `array.map()` part after the useEffect has run and the so array is updated but how to do this and why is useEffect not running the first time?

Here is the code.

```
const Results = () => {

    const options = ['movie', 'tv']; 
    const { value } = useParams(); // from router 
    const [ page, setPage ] = useState(1);
    const [ option, setOption ] = useState(options[0]);
    const [ array, setArray ] = useState([]);

    const handleMovieClick = () => {setOption('movie')}
    const handleTVShowClick = () => {setOption('tv')}

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('HERE');
        fetchArrayByPage(value, page, option).then(res => setArray(res));
    }, [value, page, option])

    console.log(array);
    console.log(option);

    return (
        <div className="results-container">
            <div>
                <ul className='categories'>
                    <button onClick={handleMovieClick}>Movies<span>{0}</span></button>
                    <button onClick={handleTVShowClick}>TV Shows<span>{0}</span></button>
                </ul>
            </div>
            {
            <div>
                <div className='results-list'>
                    {array.map((arr, index) => {
                        console.log(fetchID(arr, option));
                        return <Card key={index} id={arr} option={option}></Card>})}
                </div>

                <div className='pages'>

                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect`'s callback is fired after the render and `fetchArrayByPage` seems to be async. So clicking on "TV shows" results in:

1. `option` is changed to "tv" (`array` stays the same)
2. `console.log(array); console.log(option);`
3. render with new `option` and old `array`
4. `console.log('HERE'); fetchArrayByPage(...)`
5. some time passes
6. `setArray(res)`
7. render with new `option` and new `array`

You should call `fetchArrayByPage` from your `handle*Click` handlers:

```
const handleTVShowClick = () => {
    fetchArrayByPage(value, page, "tv").then(res => {
        setOption('tv');
        setArray(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still getting repeats. I am pretty sure it is rendering again when ``` setOption('tv')``` is called.